# Select multiple terms when filling in a managed metadata field

Tags: managed-metadata

Is it possible to select multiple terms when filling in a managed metadata field?

When I open the pop-up to select the terms, I am only able to select one term from the `treeview` and then click select to add it to the selection.

What I would like to do is being able to select multiple terms in `treeview` (by holding shift for example) and then click on select to add them all to the selection.

We have situations when people need to select a lot of terms and doing it one by one just takes to much time.

Answer (score 1):

You can double click the terms in the `treeview` and then it will be added without clicking Select button.

Comment: Double clicking is a bit faster, but users will still have to double click a lot of terms :(